# Cannot handle Spring Security exceptions

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security

I'm learning how to create a REST API using Spring Boot and everything is going well so far, but I reached my first block: I cannot handle exceptions that are thrown while I'm performing an authentication, using Spring Security.

I created an ExceptionHandler class in my project, annotated with `@ControllerAdvice`, and I'm able to catch different exceptions in my applications using a `SecurityFilterChain`, however I learned that **I can't catch exceptions thrown during authentication because those exceptions are thrown behind the DispatcherServlet and before invoking `@ControllerAdvice`.** ([Source](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-exceptionhandler))

So I tried to implement one of the solutions suggested in the tutorial linked above to handle exceptions thrown by Spring Security. This is what I did:

1. I changed my `SecurityFilterChain` implementation (code below, in Kotlin) to add the method `authEntryPoint()`.
2. I added the line `.exceptionHandling { it.authenticationEntryPoint(authEntryPoint()) }` in the SecurityFilterChain implementation below.

### SecurityFilterChain implementation

```kotlin
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfig(
    private val certProperties: CertProperties,
    @Qualifier("handlerExceptionResolver") private val resolver: HandlerExceptionResolver
) {
    @Bean
    fun securityFilterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
        return http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests {
                it.antMatchers("/v1/countries/**").authenticated()
            }
            .exceptionHandling { it.authenticationEntryPoint(authEntryPoint()) }
            .sessionManagement { it.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS) }
            .oauth2ResourceServer { it.jwt() }
            .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .build()
    }

    private fun authEntryPoint() = AuthenticationEntryPoint { request, response, authException ->
        // This code is never called
        resolver.resolveException(request, response, null, authException)
    }

    @Bean
    fun jwtDecoder() = JwtDecoder { token ->
        val signedJwt = SignedJWT.parse(token)
        val isValid = signedJwt.verify(ECDSAVerifier(certProperties.publicKey))
        if (!isValid) throw UnauthorizedException(type = "AUTH_INVALID")

        Jwt(
            token,
            signedJwt.jwtClaimsSet.issueTime.toInstant(),
            signedJwt.jwtClaimsSet.expirationTime.toInstant(),
            signedJwt.header.toJSONObject(),
            signedJwt.jwtClaimsSet.toJSONObject()
        )
    }
}
```

### RestExceptionHandler implementation

```kotlin
@ControllerAdvice
class RestExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = [AuthenticationException::class])
    fun handleApiException(ex: AuthenticationException): ResponseEntity<HttpException.Body> {
        // This code is never called
        val exception = UnauthorizedException(title = title, detail = detail)
        return ResponseEntity(exception.body, exception.status)
    }
}
```

However, if an exception is thrown by Spring Security during the authentication (for example, the JWT token is invalid and the `if` condition is called in the function `jwtDecoder()` above), the changes that I did above are still not capturing this exception:

Neither the method `authEntryPoint()` in the SecurityConfig class is called, nor the method `handleApiException()` in the class RestExceptionHandler. So instead of seeing my custom exception `UnauthorizedException`, I'm seeing the generic Spring Boot exception. I also see the following stacktrace in the logs when an exceptions is thrown by Spring Security:

### Stacktrace when an exception is thrown

```
com.learnspring.exception.UnauthorizedException: null
    at com.learnspring.config.SecurityConfig.jwtDecoder$lambda-6(SecurityConfig.kt:80) ~[main/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationProvider.getJwt(JwtAuthenticationProvider.java:97) ~[spring-security-oauth2-resource-server-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(JwtAuthenticationProvider.java:88) ~[spring-security-oauth2-resource-server-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:182) ~[spring-security-core-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.java:134) ~[spring-security-oauth2-resource-server-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:112) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:221) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? What am I missing in my code above so I can properly capture exceptions thrown by Spring Security? Thanks!

Comment: and as a response? (you get 401 + "WWW-Authenticate" header?)

Comment: @xerx593 No, if the authentication fails because the JWT is invalid and the `if` condition inside the function `jwtDecoder()` is called, then I get a HTTP 500 as a response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem (in short) is:
`com.learnspring.exception.UnauthorizedException` is none of  (no `instanceof`):

```
org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException //! v5.7.3
```

(At this stage of authentication, with your particular Filter+version ([`BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/5.7.3/oauth2/oauth2-resource-server/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/resource/web/BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.java#L132-L148)),) This is the exception type which is handled by `authenticationFailureHandler`(which should point to your particular entry point/handler(s)..), otherwise it is handled as (regular) "servlet error" (*before* mvc handlers/advices).

### Fix

Throw one (of) `org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException` within your jwt decoder.